# Describe all continuous and linear tranformations $f:(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{F}(x,y)) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$

Tags: general-topology, linear-transformations, filters

Let $\mathscr{B}=\{(-a,a)\times \mathbb{R}:a>0\}$. It's easy to see that $\mathscr{B}$ is the filter of neighborhoods of the origin in a topology compatible with the linear structure of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, namely, $\mathscr{F}(0,0)=\{U \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}: U \supset (-a,a) \times \mathbb{R} \ (\exists a>0) \}$.

I already proved that every linear tranformation $f:(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{F}(x,y)) \rightarrow )\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ of the form $f_\lambda(x,y)=\lambda x$ is continuous and that the linear transformation $\tilde{f}:(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{F}(x,y)) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ given by $\tilde{f}(x,y)=y$ is not continuous.

> **My question:** How to describe all the continuous and linear tranformations $f:(\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathscr{F}(x,y)) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$?

I believe they are all projections of the form $f_\lambda(x,y)=\lambda x$, above mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, any linear transformation $\left(\mathbb R^2, \mathscr F(x, y)\right) \to (\mathbb R, \vert\cdot\vert)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $f_1(x,y) = x$ and $\tilde f(x,y) = y$. Now, note (or prove, if it isn't given) that the sum of two continuous linear transformations with $(\mathbb R, \vert\cdot\vert)$ as range is also continuous. Can you finish from here?

Comment: How can I conclude that the discontinuous part of the linear transformation is zero?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand; discontinuous part of what linear transformation?

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous linear transformation. Then, $f(x,y)=f(1,0)f_1(x,y)+f(0,1)\tilde{f}(x,y)$. Therefore, $f(0,1)\tilde{f}(x,y)=f(x,y)-f(1,0)f_1(x,y)$. I'm calling it a discontinuous part of my linear transformation, the term $f(0,1)\tilde{f}(x,y)$.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. This is why I brought up the fact that the sum of two continuous linear transformations will still be continuous. In particular, since both of the things on the RHS of $f(0, 1) \tilde f(x, y) = f(x, y) + (-f(1, 0)) f_1(x, y)$ are continuous, then so is their sum, and thus the left hand side is continuous, despite $\tilde f(x, y)$'s discontinuity; can you finish from here?

Comment: Now I understand, thanks!